# Remove item from LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap

Small problem i am having with a program here. I am trying to create a program that adds Words to Linked Lists within a Array depending on their hashCode, determined by my hashFunction. If they have the same value for their hashCode they get added into a Linked List. I have a small count method that counts how many times a word is in the List. It works by computing the value for their hashFunction. It then goes to that value in the array, and iterates through the LinkedList until it reaches a Null value. It has a count variable which is incremented each time it finds the word in the list. This is my code:

```
public class test{

    public static class Node<T>{
       public T data;
       public Node<T> next;
       public Node(){

       }

       public Node(T data, Node<T> next)
       {
          this.data = data;
          this.next = next;
       }
    }

    static Node[] array = new Node[512];

    public static void add(String word){
        int position = hashFunction(word);
        if(array[position] == null){
            array[position] = new Node(word, null);
        }else{
            Node newHead = new Node(word, array[position]);
            array[position] = newHead;
        }
    }

    public static void remove(String word){
        int remove = hashFunction(word);
        Node head = array[remove];
        if(head.data == word){
            head = head.next;
            System.out.println("Found");
        }else if(head.data != word){
            for(; array[remove] != null; array[remove] = array[remove].next){
                if(array[remove].data == word){
                    array[remove] = array[remove].next;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Yusuf");
        }
    }

    public static int count(String word){
        int number = 0;
        int position = hashFunction(word);
        for(; array[position] != null; array[position] = array[position].next){
            if(array[position].data == word){
                number++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(number);
        return number;
    }

    public static int hashFunction(String a){
        int sum = 1;
            for(int i = 0; i<a.length(); i++){
                char b = a.charAt(i);
                int value = (int) b;
                sum *= value;
         }
         return sum % array.length;
     }

    public static void addthings(String word, int n){
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            add(word);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addthings("abc", 500000);
        count("abc");
        count("abc");
        count("abc");
        count("abc");
        }
}
```

My issue is the first time I add values in it and check how many times it occurs it works fine, but any more calls to the Count method after that returns 0 for some reason.

I have another issue too which is my remove method isn't removing the items from the Linked List I want it too. The code iterates through the List, and when it finds the item which is meant to be removed, it removes the pointer from there and points it to the next value. This isn't working however.

Can someone show me how to fix these two issues please?

Thanks.

Comment: Well on first call, the loop inside count() method gets executed and therefore returns 500000, but on every subsequent call, it doesn't enter the loop, so it means array[position] != null; is evaluated to false, I will keep looking to see what happens, will post back after dinner.

Comment: After loop in count() initializes for the first time, this line: array[position] = array[position].next assigns null to the array[38] and it was not null when loop/count() was called for the first time, first time array[38] (array[position]) is: com.company.Test$Node@4c75cab9 and for every call after that it's null, so array[position] != null; is false and your loop doesn't get executed so number stays at it's primarily initialized value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

In your function if you write something `Node head` it means you are creating some local instance for a Node. If you set `head = head.next` this will simply change the state of your local instance variable not the state of your array.

You are checking if the first node contains the data which you are looking and trying to remove it then you have to remove it from your source Array(Array in which your references reside).So you can write something like this:

```
if(head.data == word)
   array[remove] = head.next;
```

This was an example. The point is that you are not chaning things in your array but in your local variable.

```
 public static void remove(String word){
            int remove = hashFunction(word);
            Node head = array[remove];
            if(head.data == word){
                head = head.next;
                System.out.println("Found");
            }else if(head.data != word){
                for(; array[remove] != null; array[remove] = array[remove].next){
                    if(array[remove].data == word){
                        array[remove] = array[remove].next;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Yusuf");
            }
        }
```

A second mistake is in second clause where you just set `array[remove] = array[remove].next;`
 It will break your linkedlist into two different linkedlist. Suppose you have 4 elements in linkedlist `A,B,C,D` and you remove `B` and there were pointers like this `A->B->C->D` then you are adding no pointers from `A -> C`. Here you break your linkedlist.

You can use while loop that will work easily.